# Spring roo - jetty fails to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, spring-roo

I have Spring-Roo geerated project, that fails to start in jetty via `mvn jetty:run`

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/roo124/domain/Company : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

What does `Unsupported major.minor version` mean? And where can I see that 51.0 value?

Comment: Thanks to Naytzyrhc, so that means that I am trying to tun Java 7 compiled classes on JVM 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means that the classes, you are trying to run, were compiled with a newer version of java than the one you are currently using.
Please check the output of `mvn --version` and make sure you are using a current JVM.

For more information about the class file version, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/435583